# Asynchronically: 1. Posting URL and 2. Image downloading (from the given URL)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, asynchronous

I'd like to know how to download an image asynchronously.

**Using:** Codeigniter, JQuery.

**Background:**
We have a web where user can post URLs.
Given a URL we will: 
 - Fetch and prase the HTML to extract img urls (using simple_html_dom)
 - Download these images (if any) in our server (curl).
 - Publish the post done by the user.
 - Redirect user to the post published.

**Issue:**
Download images could take a while, and we dont want to block the user there.

**Need:**
There is any way to post the thread and allow the user navigate normally while we are downloading the images asynchronically since we don't need the images to appear in the post.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using AJAX calls?

Comment: What about storing the list of images that need to be downloaded in MySQL, then have a cron to work through these every X minutes. Then on the page, you can check if the local file exists and if not display a placeholder instead.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, noted. But I'd prefer a solution that doesn't required db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PHP script, `ignore_user_abort`

```
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);

// just to be safe, override the default php timeout so the script doesn't timeout for long operations
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

// download images
```

http://php.net/ignore_user_abort

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'd like to download the images while he's still connected to the page. This is, he puts the url and we redirect him to the main page to keep in the page while we are downloading the images from the URL.

Comment: So you want to keep the user on the page (i.e. block navigation) while the download operation completes, but you "dont want to block the user there"?

Comment: No, no, sorry. User may navigate freely. What I dont want is he having to wait the images download to keep navigating (in this case to be redirected to the post published).